# Should action buttons be separate or part of a single toolbar?

Tags: toolbar, admin

> This is a **follow-up question** from the previous question [managing taxonomy hierarchies UI patterns](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30864/taxonomy-hierarchy-management-ui-pattern).

Question: When an item in a list has action buttons that perform create/edit/delete actions, is it better to display each action button as a separate element or should they be grouped into a single toolbar?

**Separate Elements**

[image]

**Single Toolbar**

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Separate buttons.

Combining the buttons creates a relationship between the buttons, even though that's not really important. Placing the buttons individually within the element probably does a better job of establishing the relationship between button and item, which is more important.

Plus, it means larger target sizes. [Fitts' law](http://www.interaction-design.org/encyclopedia/fitts_law.html) and all that.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest grouping the buttons simply because I find it esthetic, but with one caveat: can you eliminate the up/down arrows?

I am assuming that this is for reordering the list item, but in this day and age, users expect to drag the list item.  Needing to move the item three rows down means clicking on the down arrow icon, moving the mouse (because the arrow’s icon has moved with the item), clicking again, etc.

**Update**: Jimmy raises a good point about the lack of affordance for drag and drop.  This can be addressed by adding three horizontal lines, an affordance that most users would recognize, I think.  The designer can further improve the UI by providing immediate feedback when the user clicks on the three lines, e.g. by drawing an outline or changing the selection color — i.e. not waiting until the user actually drags the item.

[image]

Comment: One problem with drag and drop, though, is that without affordance there's no clue it's there. Granted, in user testing I have seen users spontaneously try to drag elements, but I've also seen them fail to.

Comment: Moving the items 3 times doesn't necessarily mean you have to move the mouse every time. We can move the cursor along with the item, and in many cases we can just move the list around the item, anchoring the item in place.

Comment: Moving the mouse cursor is a big no-no; it is very disorienting to the user.  I have ran into just one app that did that in the last 28 years and hated it.  Moving the list while anchoring the item is a better option, but it doesn’t feel quite right IMO.

Comment: Without those arrow buttons you have no chance to re-order the items if you use keyboard only.

Comment: @unor: no, that is not true. You can have keyboard shortcuts without corresponding buttons. Hitting for example the up or down arrow can still move items around without there being a button to do the same thing. Having the drag icon there should be enough indication that moving items is possible.

Comment: I like the 3 horizontal lines for drag and drop affordance but that is the same as the new 'settings menu' icon in Chrome. It may not be quite as helpful for users as you'd like.

Comment: @Hisham: What affordance would you use to indicate how the user can drag-and-drop not only vertically for sort order but horiztonally for moving the selected item to a different level of the hierarchy?  The biggest issue we had with using drag-and-drop was that users had a hard time giving a node a new parent.

Comment: @Marjan: In case of a web context, using the arrow keys would conflict with the default allocation of those keys. If a user focuses an item (without providing a button you'd need to make sure this is possible), pressing key down should result in a down-scroll. Also, by "hiding" this functionality for keyboard users, those that don't read the help/manual are stucked.

Comment: @unor: that's why usually ctrl-up and ctrl-down are used. The fact that you cannot use specific keys doesn't invalidate the need to be able to perform those actions using keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Charles You didn’t indicate that you need to move items horizontally in your original question. If anything, this is an added argument for removing the up/down arrows and replacing them with drag-and-drop, otherwise you’d need to add left/right arrows as well, add things get unwieldy. As for the affordance, I would stick with drag-and-drop but remove the three grab bars on the right, and make the entire item draggable anywhere that you click except on the icons. The affordance would need to be provided as the item is being moved, e.g. using horizontal lines between items to show destination.

Answer (score 3):

@Jimmy is right about the usability aspect - in terms of Fitts' law it's indeed much preferable to separate the buttons.

However, from the visual and cognitive load aspect it may be better to group them in a toolbar. You can see from your own sketches how much visual noise is added when you separate them - instead of one background and X icons you get X backgrounds and X-1 strips of whitespace between the buttons. You also feel like there are X elements on the screen, rather than the one element of a toolbar.

Comment: Does the perception of more visual elements increase cognitive load? I'm not in doubt; I've suspected this but never seen a source confirm it.

Comment: AFAIK visual noise directly affects cognitive load, but I don't have any research to cite on this. It's a good question to ask on CogSci.SE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd mix it: group what belongs together.

In your first example, it is harder to get an overview of the provided actions (harder to distinguish).

Your second example might be harder to use, because the buttons are nearer to each other, so the click-area is smaller. But it's  straightaway clear what actions are possible.

I assume the following actions:

- Move item up
- Move item down
- Add new item (as a child of the current one?)
- Edit item
- Delete item

I'd display the edit and delete button inline right next to the item name (without the eye-catching button background color, if these actions are rarer used than move/add).

Then I'd group the two move buttons as you did in the second example, but with a higher whitespace inbetween. And then display the add button separately next to the move buttons (with more whitespace than what is used inbetween the move buttons).

So it would look like:

```
Test
  test ✍ ✖                             [↑ ↓]   [+]
    test
    child
```

Answer (score 0):

Many people are referencing Fitt's Law which is definitely relevant, but a much more applicable law is the [Gestlat Principles of Proximity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping) which state, in-part, that "perception lends itself to seeing stimuli that physically resemble each other as part of the same object, and stimuli that are different as part of a different object."

In your particular example, you want to show grouping between the list items and their independent actions, but I don't think you need to show grouping amongst just the actions. In fact, the only quality they share is that they are all actions. It's more important that they're shown in proximity to their list item, which you've already accomplished.