# What is best UI/UX solution for displaying taxonomies hierarchy in simple grid list(table view)?

Tags: gui-design, hierarchy, categorization, taxonomy

**Overview**

What we have in this release of our eCommerce software (e shop), is a simple table view with filterable search and pagination in an admin panel for managing product taxonomies.
Taxonomies have a hierarchy which can be up to 4 levels deep and at most 1000 items. For some technical reasons we cannot use a tree view.

**Requirements**

Admin user wants to find a taxonomy through this grid to :

- edit node
- delete node

*(Node creation is not in our scope because it can be done through a form in which the user can specify a parent node, while defining a new taxonomy.)*

**Research**

In my research, I found a question which does not address my specific problem, but is relevant:
[Taxonomy Hierarchy Management UI Pattern](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30864/taxonomy-hierarchy-management-ui-pattern)

**Solution A**

Showing hierarchy in a column as navigation breadcrumbs:
[image: showing hierarchy in a column as navigation breadcrumb]

**Solution B**

Showing hierarchy in title column as indent:
[image: showing hierarchy in title column as indent]

**Question**

What is the best UI/UX solution for displaying taxonomies hierarchy in simple grid list(table view)?

Comment: and why do you want it to be a grid?

Comment: my two cents: this other question may interest you: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/whats-the-best-way-to-view-a-deep-hierarchy

Comment: Have you looked into using a Tree Grid? (for example, https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtreegrid/index.htm)

Answer (score 5):

I think your second option is going to get confusing when the users will start using the sort functionality, you will lose the visual hierarchy between the elements.

I would go for the 1st option.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend sticking to **Solution A**.

Not only does it look **consistent**, but also happens to cause lesser confusion with Indentations.

You wouldn't want the User to stress out reading the different levels of Indentations. Remember, they aren't programmers to distinguish between indentations. Also Solution B lacks consistency and the hierachy doesn't make sense and will require a briefing before getting the user to play.

Comment: What's your opinion on problem with space? If there'll be like 5 levels of taxonomy, *Solution A* will take up so much space that it might not be possible to fit it in the window.

Comment: Easy. It will only show X levels up. So, say if it happens to be root>digital goods>a>b>c, only show up ...a>b>c.

Still better than Solution B.

Answer (score 2):

I vote in favor of **Solution B**, as its more compact layout, leaves room to work with spacing and colours to enhance the communication of taxonomy.

But, since your case involves thousands of items with 4 levels, I would suggest you also consider something interactive like a **[Zoomable Partition Layout](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html)**.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the second one (grouping). And when user clicks on the sort, I would sort the rows based on Group Headers (Digital, Tablet). Optionally one could even sort the rows within the Headers based on the sort order defined at the Group Header level.