# How to create a clear and editable hierarchy table?

Tags: hierarchy, information, nested-tables

I was seeing some old threads for hierarchical tables ([like this one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30864/taxonomy-hierarchy-management-ui-pattern)), but nothing quite fit my project requirements, so I thought we could update the discussion!

In my application's hierarchy feature, users can add assets to any level, and they are accessible from any level below that. For example, Asset "NA0001" in level "Region - North America" can be accessed by anyone assigned to "Chicago", but Asset "Illinois1" cannot be accessed by someone assigned to "Indiana".

I've pulled together this sketch, taking inspiration from some methods I've seen for [nested tables.](https://dribbble.com/shots/3688536-Nested-table-display)

My main goals for this design are to:

1. Make it more obvious when an asset is assigned to a specific level
   (and therefore also assigned to everything below that level)
2. More easily view/navigate the hierarchy
3. Easily assign an asset to a level

How well does this solution work?

1. Understanding the which assets are assigned to a level, versus the total
   number of assets in that level?
2. Does the "Asia" ("Asset" as a tag) or "North America" ("Asset" as text) format work better to indicate assets?
3. Do tags help to indicate hierarchy level?
4. How is the overall readability?
5. The next goal is to make it so the user can easily add an asset to any level. Would the Edit dropdown work, or should there be an inline "+ Add Asset" button at each asset level?

(This is a long question -- let me know if it should be broken up into separate questions!)
[image: Hierarchical table]